# adding a number to a cell string

Tags: matlab

I am trying to append a number to a cell string ('fract') the code is below. After executing the code though all the cells in fract_lbl are still just 'fract'.

```
fract_lbl = repmat({'fract'}, int_fract, 1);
num_vec = [1:int_fract]';
fract_lbl = strcat(fract_lbl, num2cell(num_vec));
```

How can I append a number to a cell string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ≥ R2016b, you can skip [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and concatenate strings directly with [`plus`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html) as follows:

```
Str = 'fract' + string(numvec);
```

Implicit expansion is happening in above line.

The above line gives a string array. In your question, you actually have a cell array containing characters in each cell, not strings. If you need a cell array of characters then you can further use [`cellstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) as follows:

```
Str = cellstr(Str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a function such as [compose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/compose.html), and use the format specifiers:

```
fract_new = compose('%s%d',fract_lbl{1}, num_vec)
```

assuming that the prefix `fract` remains the same.

Comment: @SardarUsama yeah nice catch